# How to delete current element if previous element is empty in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to delete element  with class "tehnicneinfo" but only if the element I'm checking ( with class "h2size") has no child. I have a bunch of those elements, generated by a plugin and I want to delete only the ones that have the next element without child. I wrote jquery code, but it delets all of my  elements, not only the ones that have the next element without child. Here is my jquery code:

```
$('.news .h2size > div').each(function() {
        var ul = $(this).find('ul');
        if(!ul.length) $(this).remove();
        var h1 = $('.news').find('.tehnicneinfo');
        var h2size = $('.news').find('.h2size');
        if(h2size.prev().is(':empty'))
        {
            h1.remove();
        }
    });
```

this code is inside `$(document).ready(function()`. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? The code is for something else also, so I'm having truble only from `var h1 = $('.news').find('.tehnicneinfo');` this line on. Thanks in advance!

Html:

```
<div class="news">
   <h1 class="tehnicneinfo">xxx</h1>
   <div class="h2size">
      <div id="xyxyxy">
        .......
      </div>
   </div>
   <h1 class="tehnicneinfo">yyy</h1>
   <div class="h2size"></div>
   ....
</div>
```

That's the html, only that there is like 20 more lines that are the same, but with different values (not yyy and xxx). I would need to delete all 'yyy' (they are not all with same value).

Comment: Can you share the HTML? You need to use the relationship between  `tehnicneinfo` and `h2size`

Comment: you want to delete all element have class tehnicneinfo under class element h2size ?

Comment: @user3029612 In your second `if` statement, try dropping the semicolon. That may very well be your problem. ;-)

Comment: I added html code. @impinball tnx, I didn't notice that, now it dosen't delete any <h1> elements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter the ones you want to remove then remove them

*"I want to delete only the ones that have the next element without child"*

```
$('.tehnicneinfo').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).next().children().length; 
    // only ones with next sibling with no children
}).remove();
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/btqe7ygL/)